# SQL script character encoding

Tags: sql-server-2008, character-encoding, ssms

I have done some changes in `.sql` file and after I try to save it, it gives me.

[image]

But the problem is I haven't use any characters that I haven't used before in that script. So, what I would like to know is if it is possible to find out which character is causing encoding to change?

Comment: I get this too sometimes. I think it's special characters, like return characters or line feeds.

Comment: Simple. Save as UTF-8 instead, see what characters it has, compare with the character set for the encoding you have been using. But why not change all your SQL files to UTF-8 anyway?

Comment: @TomBlodget All the SQL files are on `team foundation server` in my company and I should just upload new things I add to that script, but I am not allowed to change encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I have opened `.sql` file in `Notepad++` and change it to the encoding I needed. This is how I solved the problem, but that is stil not answer to the question how to determine which characters are of different `encoding` comparing to file itself.